# How to close inputStream and fileOutputstream running in a thread by using OnClick event

Tags: java, android, multithreading, media-player

i record a stream which comes from the mPlayer but cant find a way how to stop the recording onClick? How should look the stopRecord functions?
any suggestions?

here is my code.

```
        recordToggle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Thread recordingThread;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        FileOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;

        private void testMediaBuffer() {
```

Recording should run in a separate Thread but Thread.stop is deprecated

```
            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    String outputSource = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + folder + "/my.mp3";
                    try {
                        fos = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    int c;
                    try {


                        URL url = new URL(mPlayer.getDataSource());
                            inputStream = url.openStream();

                            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            con.connect();
                            int status = con.getResponseCode();
                            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(status));
                            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                            int bytesRead = 0;
                            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                            try {
                                while ((c = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                        Log.d(TAG, " bytesRead=" + bytesRead + " buf: " + Arrays.toString(buf));
                                        try {
                                            fos.write(buf, 0, c);
                                        } catch (IllegalThreadStateException | IOException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    fos.flush();
                                    bytesRead++;
                                }is.close();
                            fos.close();
                        } catch (NullPointerException | SocketException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            recordingThread.start();
        }

        //-- runnable

        private void stopRecord() throws IOException {
            //out.close();
            inputStream.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.close();
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //REC
            if (recordToggle.isEnabled()) {

                if (mPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                    getAlbumStorageDir();
                    testMediaBuffer(); 



                    play.setEnabled(false);

                } else {

                    play.setEnabled(true);
                }
            } else {

                play.setEnabled(true);
                try {
                    stopRecord();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isRunning = true;


recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                String outputSource = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + folder + "/my.mp3";
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(outputSource);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                int c;
                try {


                    URL url = new URL(mPlayer.getDataSource());
                        inputStream = url.openStream();

                        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        con.connect();
                        int status = con.getResponseCode();
                        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(status));
                        InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                        int bytesRead = 0;
                        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                        try {
                            while (isRunning && (c = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, " bytesRead=" + bytesRead + " buf: " + Arrays.toString(buf));
                                    try {
                                        fos.write(buf, 0, c);
                                    } catch (IllegalThreadStateException | IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                fos.flush();
                                bytesRead++;
                            }is.close();
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (NullPointerException | SocketException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        recordingThread.start();
    }


  public void stopRecording() {
     isRunning = false;
  }
```

This is an Example Code. 
Explanation:
 a global variable boolean indicating your recoding while its True.
 when you want to stop recording you set the variable as false.
 this will leave the while loop.
 continue with the the rest of the code inside the Thread and close the thread when the code inside run() is over.
after the while loop close the Streams while you inside the thread.

Comment: where did you the place isRunning it should be inside the loop header outside the functions and on the Stop function

Comment: variable isRunning is never used. when i set it to final is "isRunning" always true.

Comment: its as you mentioned: first inside the testMediaBuffer() function before recordingThread and then within the loop and finally inside stopRecord() within the testMediaBuffer() function

Comment: i get an error for isRunning inside the while loop. variable is accessed from within inner class. needs to be declared final

Comment: Thank you very much your idea saved me a lot of time. i simply set a isRunning variable into the onClick event and as you suggested additional into the while loop. _O_